# What are the effects of challenging the boss with multiple skulls active?

Tags: wizard-of-legend

When you reach the boss chamber, the sigil on the boss's gravestone is surrounded three interlinked skulls.

[image: Three skulls lit up]

Defeating enemies on the level darkens these skulls one by one.

[image]

Does the number of lit up skulls have any effect on the boss fight?

Answer (score 1):

### More skulls = more small enemies to deal with during the boss battle

Couldn't find anything on the wiki or any fan sites, so I decided to just test it out myself to see what stands out.

### Boss with 0 skulls

[image: 0 Skulls]

With all the skulls off, only two additional enemies spawn with the boss.

### Boss with 3 skulls

[image: 3 Skulls]

With every skull still on, 6 additional enemies spawn with the boss.

---

The number of skulls doesn't seem to affect health or moveset, so it seems more  skulls just means having a busier boss battle. Additionally, it seems the extra enemies spawned by having skulls lit up are always just [Ghouls](https://wizardoflegend.gamepedia.com/Ghoul), so if your current loadout isn't ready for crowd control, you might want to clear out more of your current floor first.